# Generate a random number up to 50. Have the user guess up to 5 times what that random number is using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning Java Script and would like to know what's wrong with my code. I want to generate a random up to 50 and then have the user guess up to 5 times what the random number is.

Thanks in advance.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>

var random = Math.floor(math.random()*51);
var user = prompt("Guess my number");
var guess ="";

function myFunction() {
for (var i=0; i < 6; i++) {


if (user != random) {
        alert('try again');
        guess+=1;
    else if (user == random) {
        alert('You win!');
        }
 return alert('Sorry, you lose!');
     };
   }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to have the user guess up to 5 times. So I thought a loop would be best.

Comment: Remove `loop`, use a counter...

Comment: But nothing is showing though when I open up the window.

Comment: Why would the counter be better over a loop? Still learning Java Script

Comment: How exactly would I return a statement telling the user to stop guessing once he or she reaches 5 max tries using a counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good practice to encapsulate code into self invoking function

```
(function() {

//your code here

})()
```

it helps to prevent variables from littering the global scope and makes your code running instantly. And you don't need to use `onload="myFunction()"` now.
Here is version with for loop:

```
(function () {

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);

    function myFunction() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i != 5) {
                var user = prompt("Guess my number");
                if (user != random) {
                    alert('try again');
                } else if (user == random) {
                    alert('You win!');

                }
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, you lose!');
            }
        }
    }

    myFunction(); //invoking function

})()
```

Comment: A helpful alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer this example:

```js
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51); //Get random number
//----------------------^^ Typo here
var guess = 0;

function myFunction() { //Invoke this function on page load
  if (guess < 6) { //test the counter every time 
    var user = prompt("Guess my number");
    if (user != random) {
      alert('try again');
      guess += 1; //Increase the counter
      myFunction(); //Invoke the function again
    } else if (user == random) {
      alert('You win!');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, you lose!');
  }
};
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
```